# Multi-Dimensional Array - Array of arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string containing numbers as a 2D matrix. I'm trying to use `Split` function to split the contents of a `string` into an array. So, when I do:

```
String[] subStrs = new String[20];
subStrs = str.Split('\n');
```

The code above works fine. However, when I try to create a 2D array and try to populate sub-arrays using the same way:

```
String[,] numbers = new String[20,20];
for (int i = 0; i < subStrs.Length; i++ )
{
    numbers[i] = subStrs[i].Split(' '); //Error
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

> Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2.

If 2D array is really an array of arrays, then why is the statement `numbers[i] = subStrs[i].Split(' ');` illegal?

**PS :** I do know that I can use a nested loop instead to populate `numbers`. I'm just curious why can't I use the above method?

Comment: There's no point in creating arrays that you're going to immediately overwrite with a new array.  Only create a new array when you actually intend to access the values of that array.

Comment: `string[,]` and `string[][]` are two different things. `Split` returns a `string[]` so it can be added to an array of arrays (i.e. `string[][]`), but not a 2D array `string[,]` without some more work (i.e. you'd need an inner loop to assign values to the correct cells in a `string[,]`)

Comment: @Servy I'm sorry, I didn't understand your comment. Could you please elaborate that?

Comment: @Dumbledore You're creating an array and then immediately throwing it away and assigning a new array to that variable.  That's pointless.  Just don't create a new array if you're just going to throw it away and assign a new array to that variable without using it.

Comment: @Servy Are you talking about `subStrs`?

Comment: @Servy Just one last thing. I don't think I'm overwriting `subStrs` anywhere. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `subStrs = str.Split('\n'); ` is overwriting the previous value of `subStrs`.  It's overwriting the value of the variable that had previously pointed to the array you just created (and never used) and replacing that value with the array returned by `Split`.

Comment: @Servy Ohh, so you mean I shouldn't have initialized `subStrs`. Yes, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Dumbledore Well, you should initialize it, but you should initialize it to *the return value of `Split`*, rather than initializing it to a value that you never need it to have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If 2D array is really an array of arrays

It's not.  A 2D array is just that, a 2D array.

An array of arrays is an array of arrays:

```
string[][]
```

If you have an array of arrays, then the item at each index of the outer array is another array.  If you have a 2D array then both dimensions are needed to get at a value, which is itself the value of the array, not another dimension.